# Using Plumatic Schema to coerce to bigdec

Tags: clojure, coercion, plumatic-schema

I have incoming data of the type `{:loan/amount 1200}`.

Would it be possible to use plumatic [Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) to coerce this to `{:loan/amount 1200M}`, ie coercing numbers (or even strings of digits) to bigdecimals?

I don't how to define a new data type (like `s/Bigdec`) and then make sure it uses `clojure.core/bigdec` to coerce a certain value to a `java.math.BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two separate concepts in Schema: validation and coercion.

For the first one you need to define your schema. Classes are treated as schemas so you don't need to create a custom one for `java.math.BigDecimal`. Your schema might look like:

```
(require '[schema.core :as s])
(require '[schema.coerce :as c])

(s/defschema Loan {:loan/amount java.math.BigDecimal})
```

Now you can validate your data against the schema:

```
(s/validate Loan {:loan/amount 10M})
;; => {:loan/amount 10M}
```

Now if you have some data that you would like to coerce you need to define a coercion function which is a matcher from a desired target schema (`java.math.BigDecimal` in your case) to a function that will convert the actual value to the desired `bigdec` value.

```
(def safe-bigdec (c/safe bigdec)
```

`schema.coerce/safe` is a utility function which wraps the original function and if the original one throws an exception when called, `safe` will return original input value instead of throwing the exception.

Our matcher function will check if the current schema element is `BigDecimal` and return converting function or `nil` otherwise (meaning there is no coercion for other types):

```
(defn big-decimal-matcher [schema]
  (when (= java.math.BigDecimal schema)
    safe-bigdec))
```

And finally we need a coercer for performing actual coercion:

```
(def loan-coercer (c/coercer Loan big-decimal-matcher))
```

With all the setup we can now use our coercer:

```
(loan-coercer {:loan/amount "12.34"})
;; => {:loan/amount 12.34M}

(loan-coercer {:loan/amount 1234})
;; => {:loan/amount 1234M}

(loan-coercer {:loan/amount "abc"})
;; => #schema.utils.ErrorContainer{:error {:loan/amount (not (instance? java.math.BigDecimal "abc"))}}
```

Comment: Wov, thanks a lot @piotrek-bzdyl! This was just what I needed (and I hope others need too).